# seamless login experience for sharepoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, login

I would like to know what is the best way to login into SharePoint Online without users entering any credentials. I have seen Azur being mentioned not sure the best route. What other solutions are users using.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen Azure AD and Windows 10 listed as work arounds by enabling Single Sign On. Other than that we are in the same boat here, we want it to be like our current intranet but that is an on prem SharePoint 2007  setup.